# Save Workspace MFC C++ MDI

Tags: c++, mfc, save, mdi, workspace

I have a MFC MDI application. The app can have 2 or more dialogs open. I want to implement the "Save Workspace" feature so that the user, when opening the workspace next time, opens the dialogs that were opened when he saved and closed the workspace. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is built into the [CMDIFrameWndEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984374.aspx) implementation. [SaveMDIState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983717.aspx) stores the current setup, while [LoadMDIState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982432.aspx) restores it. The documentation also explains, how to persist the position and size of the frame window itself, in case that's something you want, too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is accomplished by storing the current state of the application into some sort of persistent store.  Depending on your architecture this could be a local configuration file (xml, json, etc) stored under the Windows User's profile directory (you could also use the Windows Registry), a remote store such as a database could be used or perhaps such state could be stored into cloud storage.  Just depends on how the application currently handles configuration and how universal you want to make the state storage.

You will want to implement some sort or running history of UI state.  Storing the currently open windows and their locations when they are loaded, closed and moved.  Inject a history tracker into each MDI child that is created.  This could be a singleton type in the MDI parent.  It should have facility to look up a window by its handle and should store the relevant information in a structure that makes sense for serialization.  In each of the afore mentioned events add calls to the tracker with the appropriate changes.   The tracker should persist along whatever  rules you determine are appropriate.

The load process then requires that the MDI parent interrogate the tracker after it has initialized with what ever stored state existed.  Using the stored information (window type and location (and data?)) the MDI parent then opens up the appropriate children at the appropriate locations.

Comment: You don't have to track position/size changes or the creation/destruction of items to dump a snapshot of the current state. MFC doesn't, and still implements save/restore.

Comment: Depends on what your requirements are.  May be that is all that is required. 
What if you need to recover from shutdowns that are not expected?
What if you want to be able to store states between separate machines on different networks?